# Remove white border when using subplot and imshow in python (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, imshow

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

i use the following code to save an image

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
ax.axis                 ('off')
ax.imshow               (array[:,:,0,0,0])
fig.savefig             ("file.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

However, what I get is
[image]
and this obviously still has a white border. 
How do I get rid of it?

---

The array.shape is: (256, 256, 1, 1, 3)

Comment: Could you try to use `savefig("file.png", bbox_inches = 'tight',
    pad_inches = 0)`?

Comment: already tried it, doesn't work either... (doesn't change anything actually)

Comment: Without full code it  hard to help you because problem comes from aspect ratio and dpi of your image.

Comment: added some more.
the array i want to plot is read in and has the given shape.
there is nothing more in my code actually

Comment: What is about shape of array?

Comment: as i wrote above: array.shape gives (256, 256, 1, 1, 3)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at my example it may help you:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def save_image(data, filename):
    sizes = np.shape(data)     
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(1. * sizes[0] / sizes[1], 1, forward = False)
    ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    ax.imshow(data)
    plt.savefig(filename, dpi = sizes[0], cmap='hot') 
    plt.close()

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (256, 256))
save_image(data, '1.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the `cmap` argument be passed to `imshow` instead? Your image looks like the old `jet`, if I run the code I see `viridis` as expected.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sizes[1] / sizes[0]`?

Answer (score 5):

Little modification to above answer:

```
def save_image(data, filename):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1, 1))
    ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    ax.imshow(data, cmap="gray")
    fig.savefig(filename, dpi=data.shape[0]) 
    plt.close(fig)
```