# How to log scale a 2D Matrix / Image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, librosa, spectrogram

I have a 2D numpy array of a audio spectrogram and I want to save it as an image.

I'm using [librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/index.html) library to get the spectrum. And I can also plot it using `librosa.display.specshow()` function. There are number of different scaling types as you can see below.

```py
import PIL
import librosa
import librosa.display

def display_spectrogram(spectrum, sampling_rate):
    """
    Frequency types:
    ‘linear’, ‘fft’, ‘hz’ : frequency range is determined by the FFT window and sampling rate.
    ‘log’ : the spectrum is displayed on a log scale.
    ‘mel’ : frequencies are determined by the mel scale.
    ‘cqt_hz’ : frequencies are determined by the CQT scale.
    ‘cqt_note’ : pitches are determined by the CQT scale.
    """

    librosa.display.specshow(spectrum, sr=sampling_rate, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
    plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
    plt.title('Spectrogram')
    plt.show()
```

I can also transform the spectrogram (a numpy array) to an image and save like below.

```py
img = PIL.Image.fromarray(spectrum)
img.save("out.png")
```

---

I have the original spectrogram (linear scaled) and I want to save it with y-axis in log scale. I looked into the [library's source code](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/a53fa56bdb6695a994008d5b6ccd0100870a6036/librosa/display.py#L934) in order to understand how it scaled but cannot figure it out.

How can I log scale the y-axis of an image / 2D numpy array ?

---

[image: linear matrix]
[image: log scaled result]

Comment: @Antimon I don't want to change the values, I just want to squeeze them logarithmically.

Comment: Nevermind, I misinterpreted your problem. I understand now. But you will have to tell us what the format of the numerical data is. How are the frequencies and time points indexed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual log-transform of the Y axis is done by matplotlib. You can test this by doing `ax.set_yscale('linear')` vs `ax.set_yscale('linear')`. So the easiest alternative would be to tweak the matplotlib figure to remove ticks, borders etc. Here is one example of that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810568/1967571

If you want to do the log-scaling yourself, the steps are

- Compute the current frequencies on Y axis. Using [librosa.fft_frequencies](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.fft_frequencies.html)
- Compute the desired frequencies on Y axis. Using `numpy.logspace` or similar
- Sample the spectrogram at the desired frequencies, using for example [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) (interp1d)

Comment: Thanks @jonnor. using ```plt.axis("off")``` and ```plt.tight_layout(pad=0)``` I saved the images. It solves the problem with a different approach